# Quad monitor setup

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg

Hello I am battling with the following issue.

Setup:
Zotac MI643
Club3D CSV6400
4x Lenovo T24i-2L
Arch Linux

I simply want to add another (4th monitor). A triple monitor setup is already working fine.
However, when I want to add the fourth monitor (which should be supported by the Zotac machine and the DP MST adapter) it fails. Whenever I want to add the monitor via xrandr, the monitor is recognized as connected, although the xrandr command `xrandr --output DP-2-1-1 --auto` fails with the message `xrandr: cannot find crtc for output DP-2-1-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graphics unit (iGPU in [Core i5-10210U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/195436/intel-core-i510210u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz.html#tab-blade-1-0-4)) supports up to three displays. You cannot make this work.

Comment: Thank you, is there a chance if I added USB graphics card?

Comment: Sure, but there really is only one type of USB graphics adapter: DisplayLink. Limited compatibility, especially with Linux. Limited performance, too. Enough for dashboards, but is it enough for you? Your question does not mention a use case.

Comment: Thank you Daniel B, basically it is for text processing (LaTeX, Markdown and Browsing) and once in a while a YouTube -Video. So not that hard on the graphics chip - at least that's what I hope.

Comment: That should work just fine. I worked (software dev) for years driving two 1440p displays with a DisplayLink docking station.

Comment: Thank you very much (I am working as a politicial science and computer science teacher ;))