# USB 3.0 Graphics Card Quad Monitor Setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, usb-3, thunderbolt

the CPU is only capable of supporting three displays. Is there a chance to push the limit by adding a USB / Thunderbolt Graphics Card?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1716069/quad-monitor-setup

Comment: Are we still talking about a  Zotac MI643? It does not have much space. See https://www.pcworld.com/article/427549/how-to-create-an-insane-multiple-monitor-setup-with-three-four-or-more-displays.html Perhaps an external graphics card can help?